# Steam won't allow Black Ops 2 to be downloaded/installed to a separate drive

Tags: steam

I just bought Black Ops II on Steam, but I'm having trouble at this point. I saw a similar post on this website about Modern Warfare 3 ([I'm unable to specify which Steam library I want to install MW3 to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97082/im-unable-to-specify-which-steam-library-i-want-to-install-mw3-to)) where the option to install to a separate drive ceased to appear, but the selected answer (creating a symbolic link to the preferred drive) didn't work for me. I did attempt to change the command to fit my situation (C: being my SSD, D: being my HDD):

mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\Call of Duty Black Ops II\" "D:\SteamLibrary\Call of Duty Black Ops II\"

And I then tried installing Black Ops II from Steam, but it still recognized that there wasn't enough space on my SSD and wouldn't install it. I'm quite at a loss about what to do now. Keep in mind that my HDD is already completely set up as a separate drive, and many of my Steam games are already installed to it.

Comment: While I can guess that you want to know how to get Black Ops 2 to install to a different drive, your question's clarity could be improved by actually asking for that.

Comment: @skovacs1 Is that actually unclear?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not particularly. I was merely suggesting an improvement for this user's first post. In this instance, despite not asking the question explicitly, they only describe a situation and assume it's clear enough. While it works in this instance, in the general case, clarity is greatly improved by directly asking the question.

Comment: Did you use an administrator account to run that command? Running `mklink` to create a link under `Program Files (x86)` probably requires admin privileges.

Comment: Also, confirm that BO2 actually does install to the `steamapps/` folder. Most games go in `steamapps/common/`, not `steamapps/`.

Comment: @skovacs1 That's a fair point. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, I'm fairly certain my account has administrator privelages. A folder was created in steamapps/common, so I assume up to that point the execution worked fine.

Comment: @skovacs1, thanks for pointing that out! I don't believe I was entirely ambiguous, but I certainly could have added a bit of clarity to the issue.

Comment: This [Steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3058044&highlight=mw3) is for MW3, but it has an answer from a volunteer moderator which seems to suggest that it can't be installed because it doesn't use the new content delivery method. Having said that, I am fairly sure that I installed Black Ops 2 on my HDD when Steam is on my SSD, so that might not be the reason in this case.

Comment: Just got home and checked my installation. I installed Black Ops 2 to my HDD. So I was able to choose the installation path.

Comment: Running a command under administrator account is *not* the same as running with administrator privileges. You need to start cmd.exe as an administrator to run commands that require admin privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Steam has probably made a library folder on the drive that you installed the Steam client on. If you *don't have any games on that drive* and *don't intend to ever install any on it,* go to *Steam*>*Settings*>*Downloads*>*Steam Library Folders*, select the library folder of the drive you *don't want to install any games whatsoever to*, and click "*Remove*".

Furthermore, you can use the same method (except you click "*Add*" and not "*Remove*") to add another Steam library folder.